# View and Table collective name/type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a database table which has a column that stores the name of a table or view. Calling my column "ViewOrTableName" seems a bit clumsy. Is there a generic type/name that could mean "table" or "View"?

Specifically I'm doing this in MS SQL, if the vernacular varies.

Comment: Aside from this being primarily opinion based why do you need to store this in a table?

Comment: Seems like you're mixing data and metadata together, which is rarely correct (e.g. you cannot add a constraint to this table that references the metadata objects to enforce that it really is valid). The only more generic name I can think of under SQL Server naming is "Object", but of course that includes stored procs and other objects too.

Comment: DataSource might be a more generic name but could be more than just a table or view. The whole thing screams of something gone wrong in the design though.

Comment: The user can run a job to cause an XML file to be produced. The XML file has an element named "PartNumber" for example. Perhaps when rendering the file for one recipient he can render a part's part number, for the next recipient he can render the part's "Published Part Number" instead. So the user has some control of specifying the source of the data to use. The data source might be on a different view/table, or a different column. Hence I have a table that stores the user-selected source. We don't expose the schema to the user. The user chooses from aliased entities/properties on a website.

Answer (score 2):

The [T-SQL documentation for `FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) says

> ## FROM (Transact-SQL)
>
> Specifies the tables, views, derived tables, and joined tables used in
>   DELETE, SELECT, and UPDATE statements in SQL Server 2017.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
> <table_source> ::=   
> {  
>     table_or_view_name [ [ AS ] table_alias ]   
>         [ <tablesample_clause> ]   
>         [ WITH ( < table_hint > [ [ , ]...n ] ) ]   
>     | rowset_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]   
>         [ ( bulk_column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]   
>     | user_defined_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
>     | OPENXML <openxml_clause>   
>     | derived_table [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]   
>     | <joined_table>   
>     | <pivoted_table>   
>     | <unpivoted_table>  
>     | @variable [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
>     | @variable.function_call ( expression [ ,...n ] )   
>         [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ (column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]  
>     | FOR SYSTEM_TIME <system_time>   
> }
> ```

So maybe you'd like to use **`table_source`**, or **`table_or_view_name`**.